# Using Unicorn locally with config file in a Rails 4 app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, unicorn

If I run `rails s`, it uses Unicorn, which is great. But how can I run Unicorn with that and also use my config file?

Right now I have to do this: `bundle exec unicorn -p 3000 -c ./config/unicorn.rb`

But if there was some shorter way to fire up the server (ie. `rails s`), that'd be useful.

Comment: Would adding a Procfile and running `foreman start` work? Or do you really want to get this working typing only `rails s`?

Comment: no accepted answers - no good answer, only bad answers... Seems highly important to you.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution would be to create a shell script, at the root of your  project.

start_unicorn

```
#!/bin/bash
bundle exec unicorn -p 3000 -c ./config/unicorn.rb
```

Make sure it's executable
`chmod +x start_unicorn`

Then `./start_unicorn`

Tada!

As far as I can tell, the problem you're trying to fix is not having to type that thing out everytime.

Answer (score -1):

To include the `config/unicorn.rb` file, you could use the `rack-handlers` [gem](https://github.com/godfat/rack-handlers)

Without the need of the `config/unicorn.rb` you could use the `unicorn-rails` [gem](https://github.com/samuelkadolph/unicorn-rails).

1. Simply add the wanted gem to your Gemfile
2. run `bundle`
3. start your rails unicorn server with
   `rails s unicorn`

Comment: That doesn't pull the config file that I mentioned.

Comment: ok - I overlooked that requirement and updated my answer accordingly